# В чем разница между xenial и bionic?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Установил новую `ubuntu 18.04` и обнаружил, что она `bionic`, а до этого я использовал `xenial` и у меня возник вопрос: а чем они отличаются? Установил несколько `ppa` репозиториев с `xenial` и вроде все работает.

Comment: Очевидно, xenial старая, bionic новая. PPA работают, потому что повезло и не оказалось несовместимостей

Comment: bionic и xenial это просто кодовые названия.

Comment: xenial - это 16.04 https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Список_версий_Ubuntu

Comment: Работают ваши ppa репозитории скорее всего потому что у них есть версии пакетов и для bionic, и для xenial. В популярных репозиторях часто так бывает.

Comment: https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=48497